# jqGrid: setCell clears the column value

Tags: jqgrid, cell, updates

I am trying to update the cell value of a particular column in my grid. I am using local JSON for populating the grid `datatype: "local"`.

The column definition of that column is as follows:-

```js
{
            name: 'details',
            index: 'details',
            label: 'Details',
            editable: false,
            align: 'center',
            formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                if (rowObject['verified']) {
                    return 'sdfsfsd'; // actually hyperlink for the cellvalue
                }

                return '';
            }
}
```

I am using the following line of code to update the cell value:-

```js
// rowid is 1
grid.jqGrid('setCell', 1, 'details', 'DONE!');
```

Also tried like this:

```js
// the last parameter true to force update
grid.jqGrid('setCell', 1, 'details', 'DONE!', null, null, true);
```

However, the cell value is cleared out (cell becomes empty, `<td>` content is empty). This happens only for this column, and not for other columns in the grid. What am I missing?

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Answer (score 0):

If you use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) you should specify unformatter too. The function `formatter` will be used to set the value in the cell. At the beginning of cell editing jqGrid need to *get* the value from the cell. The function [unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#unformatting) do the job.

Comment: Yes. The technique seems to be working. It seems that the unformat is called many times, whenever required. So I need to identify the situation in which I need to return a different value. For instance, in all cases, the cell has a link, and unformat should stay mute. When I click the link, i make an AJAX call, and upon success, the link should be changed into some text. Is there a way in the grid to help identify different situations? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Oleg, I am not do cell editing by the way. I have change the cell value from a link to plain text, upon some event. I don't understand where the unformat plays its part.